# Google Chrome, Mac: Unpinned tabs reopening on startup

Tags: google-chrome, mac

I know this question has been asked on this platform before but I can't find any sources for a Mac having this problem.

I unpin tabs and close them. After I quit and close Chrome, upon restarting it the same pinned tabs are there again. How can I permanently unpin them?

I'm on a macOS Catalina version 10.15.3.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try to play around with the **On startup** Chrome settings ([chrome://settings/onStartup](http://chrome://settings/onStartup)) and check that you don't have **Open a specific page or set of pages** selected, even though that shouldn't set the tabs as pinned.

Then you can double check you're not using any extension that might override Chrome's settings. There are a few browser extensions (like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/forever-pinned/nigigpmchbpkjjgncmpiggfnikllldlh?hl=en-GB) or [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-pinned-tabs/anmidgajdonkgmmilbccfefkfieajakd)) that can force that behavior.